# Найти похожие слова в файле из списка и вывести их кол-во и название

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, поиск

Хочу сделать так, чтобы программа искала похожие слова из списка в текстовом файле и выводила их число вместе с количеством.

Вот мои наброски:

```
import urllib.request
import csv

# список сигнатур
signature = ['hack', 'fuck', 'deface', 'fsociety', 'hacker', 'scriptkiddy']

res = urllib.request.urlopen("http://kcybs.com/").read()    # адрес сайта
file_name = "C:\\Users\\tk240\\Desktop\\Qtest\\test.txt"    # путь к файлу для записи html сайта
f = open(file_name, 'wb')                                   # открывает файл
f.write(res)                                                # записывает в файл html сайта

f = open(file_name, encoding='utf8')
var_txt = f.read()
c = var_txt.count(signature)

print(signature)
print(c)
```

Но, как мы знаем, `count` не принимает строки.
Так вот: как можно это реализовать по-другому?

Comment: попробуйте запустить цикл который идет до конца файла, и если слово в тексте есть в sidnature, то count = count + 1

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N так тоже не получилось: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N , я использовал for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

sig_list = ('hack', 'fuck', 'deface', 'fsociety', 'hacker', 'scriptkiddy')

# 1/ получим текст с сайта и переведем в нижний регистр
data = requests.get('https://kcybs.com/').text.lower()

# словарь где ключ это сигнатура, а значение это количество
sigs = {}
# 2/ для каждой сигнатуры получаем количество
for sig in sig_list:
    count = data.count(sig)
    sigs[sig] = count

# 2/ более короткий вариант
sigs = {sig: data.count(sig) for sig in sig_list}

print(sigs)
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень сильно помогли, буду развиваться дальше :)

Comment: как  я понял, он берёт текст с сайта, а мне нужно html, но всё равно спасибо, попробую что-нибудь слепить из этого :)

Comment: html - это разметка, по факту это и есть текст сайта. Метод `get` получает страницу если бы вы ее сохранили без картинок через браузер, т.е. в исходном виде.